# Spreadsheet::ParseExcel $cell->value() returning undef

Tags: excel, perl, undef

I am new to perl and having trouble with the spreadsheet excel parser module.

WHen I use $cell->value() on its own line, there appears to be no problem, however when I try to use this to insert the value into an array, it returns undef, code show below:

```
for my $row ($row_min .. $row_max) {
    my @line;
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max) {
                my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                $value = $cell->value;
                push @line, $value if defined($cell);
                print $cell->value;
                print Dumper $line;
                }

         }
}
```

Here print $cell->value; returns the contents of the cell but print Dumper $line; returns undef

Comment: What is `$line`? Do you mean `print Dumper (\@line);` ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I was using Dumper incorrectly and the getvalue was actually working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Exactly such errors are very easy capture using: `use strict; use warnings;` You have a happy day, because is very common than nobody bother with questions what dosen't contains use strict and use warnings;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to push `$cell->value`not `$value`

```
push @line, $cell->value if defined($cell);
```

You should add `use strict` at the beginning of your program, so you get an error message in such a case.

Comment: sorry - typo, now fixed (however using push @line, $cell->value if defined($cell); also returns undef)

Comment: try changing `$value = $cell->value;` to `my $value = $cell->value;`.

Comment: @JamesJiimmy and when you do `push @line, \$value` ?